# Grouping sets is not aggregating results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, grouping-sets

I've only recently started using this function, so forgive this question if it is imbecilic.

I have an existing query, which I've realised could be helped with the use of this query to create additional group by groupings, akin to subtotals.

In this example, I am wanting to aggregate in a hierarchy like this:

Year > Month > Profit Centre > Date

An example of the results this query is bringing back

[image]

As you can see my grouping sets are returning zero. 
My question is, why?

My query is below

```
SELECT 
datepart(yyyy,overview.Date) as 'Year', 
datepart(mm,overview.Date) as'Month',
overview.Date as 'Date',
overview.[Profit Centre],
overview.[Current 
Year Group Bookings],
overview.[Previous Year Group Bookings],
overview.[Current Year Total Covers],
overview.[Previous Year Total Covers],
overview.[Large Group Count]

FROM
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT
CONVERT(date,csd.tendered_date_time) as 'Date',
PCM.profit_center_name as 'Profit Centre',
PCD.profit_center_id,
(
SELECT count(csd2.num_covers)
FROM ig_Business..check_sales_detail csd2
INNER JOIN ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension PCD2 (NOLOCK) ON 
PCD2.profit_center_dim_id = CSD2.profit_center_dim_id and PCD2.ent_id = 1
WHERE PCD2.profit_center_id = PCD.profit_center_id
AND CONVERT(date,CSD2.tendered_date_time) = 
CONVERT(date,CSD.tendered_date_time)
AND CSD2.num_covers >= 
(CASE 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '77' THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '13' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') THEN '16'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '14' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '90' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '98' THEN '8' 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '194' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '49' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '74' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '26' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '57' THEN '10'
END)
) as 'Current Year Group Bookings',
(
SELECT count(csd2.num_covers)
FROM ig_Business..check_sales_detail csd2
INNER JOIN ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension PCD2 (NOLOCK) ON 
PCD2.profit_center_dim_id = CSD2.profit_center_dim_id and PCD2.ent_id = 1
WHERE PCD2.profit_center_id = PCD.profit_center_id
AND CONVERT(date,CSD2.tendered_date_time) = 
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month,-12,CSD.tendered_date_time))
AND CSD2.num_covers >= 
(CASE 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '77' THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '13' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') THEN '16'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '14' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '90' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '98' THEN '8' 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '194' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '49' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '74' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '26' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '57' THEN '10'
END)
) as 'Previous Year Group Bookings',

(
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(csd2.num_covers),0)
FROM ig_Business..check_sales_detail csd2
INNER JOIN ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension PCD2 (NOLOCK) ON 
PCD2.profit_center_dim_id = CSD2.profit_center_dim_id and PCD2.ent_id = 1
WHERE PCD2.profit_center_id = PCD.profit_center_id
AND CONVERT(date,CSD2.tendered_date_time) = 
CONVERT(date,CSD.tendered_date_time)
AND CSD2.num_covers >= 
(CASE 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '77' THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '13' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') THEN '16'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '14' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '90' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '98' THEN '8' 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '194' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '49' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '74' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '26' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '57' THEN '10'
END)

) as 'Current Year Total Covers',


(
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(csd2.num_covers),0)
FROM ig_Business..check_sales_detail csd2
INNER JOIN ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension PCD2 (NOLOCK) ON 
PCD2.profit_center_dim_id = CSD2.profit_center_dim_id and PCD2.ent_id = 1
WHERE PCD2.profit_center_id = PCD.profit_center_id
AND CONVERT(date,CSD2.tendered_date_time) = 
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month,-12,CSD.tendered_date_time))
AND CSD2.num_covers >= 
(CASE 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '77' THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '13' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') THEN '16'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '14' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '90' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '98' THEN '8' 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '194' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '49' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '74' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '26' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '57' THEN '10'
END)
) as 'Previous Year Total Covers',


(CASE 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '77' THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '13' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') THEN '16'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '14' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '90' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '98' THEN '8' 
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '194' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '49' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '74' THEN '15'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '26' THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') THEN '8'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') THEN '10'
WHEN PCD.profit_center_id = '57' THEN '10'
END) AS 'Large Group Count'


FROM ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension PCD (NOLOCK) ON 
PCD.profit_center_dim_id = CSD.profit_center_dim_id and PCD.ent_id = 1
INNER JOIN it_cfg..Profit_Center_Master PCM (NOLOCK) ON PCM.profit_center_id 
= PCD.profit_center_id and PCm.ent_id = 1 
WHERE  
 ( 
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '77' AND csd.num_covers > 8)      
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '13' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)        
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('60','61','62','63','64','65') AND 
csd.num_covers > 16) 
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = 14 AND csd.num_covers >= 10)      
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = 90 AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = 98 AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('74','101') AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '194' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '49' AND csd.num_covers >= 15)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('20','21','22','200') AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '74' AND csd.num_covers >= 15)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '26' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
OR    
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('86','68') AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('40','41','42','43') AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('96','98','99') AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
OR
  (pcd.profit_center_id = '57' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
)  
AND
CSD.tendered_date_time > CONVERT(date,'2017-01-01') -- We only want 
comparisons from today going forward, i.e. not historical


GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS
(
(csd.tendered_date_time, PCM.profit_center_name,PCD.profit_center_id),
(datepart(yyyy,csd.tendered_date_time),datepart(mm,csd.tendered_date_time), 
pcm.profit_center_name),
()

)


) overview

ORDER BY overview.[Profit Centre] asc, CONVERT(date,overview.Date) asc
```

Comment: Can you post the sample data and what your expected output would be? Please post the sample data in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), or in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My question is, why (are the grouping sets zero)?*

Because you are not using aggregate functions such as `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in a manner than can be summarised into sub-totals. You are using a set of "correlated subqueries" which do use `COUNT()` but by the time these are evaluated the outer query just sees those columns as data (not as aggregates).

example (untested of course):

```
WITH pcd AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM ig_Dimension..Profit_Center_Dimension pcd
      WHERE (
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '13' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = 14 AND csd.num_covers >= 10)   -- is it an integer? or not?
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '26' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '49' AND csd.num_covers >= 15)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '57' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '74' AND csd.num_covers >= 15)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '77' AND csd.num_covers > 8)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = 90 AND csd.num_covers >= 10)   -- is it an integer? or not?
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = 98 AND csd.num_covers >= 8)    -- is it an integer? or not?
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id = '194' AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('20', '21', '22', '200') AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('40', '41', '42', '43')  AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65') AND csd.num_covers > 16)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('74', '101')      AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('86', '68')       AND csd.num_covers >= 8)
            OR (pcd.profit_center_id IN ('96', '98', '99') AND csd.num_covers >= 10)
            )
      AND pcd.ent_id = 1
      )
SELECT
      DATEPART(yyyy, csd.tendered_date_time) AS 'Year'
    , DATEPART(mm, csd.tendered_date_time)   AS 'Month'
    , pcd.[Profit Centre]
    , pcm.profit_center_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS 'Profit Centre'
    , pcd.profit_center_id
    , COUNT(csd.num_covers)
FROM ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail csd
INNER JOIN pcd ON pcd.profit_center_dim_id = csd.profit_center_dim_id
INNER JOIN it_cfg..Profit_Center_Master pcm ON pcm.profit_center_id = pcd.profit_center_id
      AND pcm.ent_id = 1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (  DATEPART(yyyy, csd.tendered_date_time) AS 'Year'
    , DATEPART(mm, csd.tendered_date_time)   AS 'Month'
    , pcd.[Profit Centre]
    , pcm.profit_center_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS 'Profit Centre'
    , pcd.profit_center_id
    )
```

NOTE: you need to be careful about "implicit conversions", if pcd.profit_center_id is an integer then do NOT use '194', but if it is a varchar or similar then do not use integers. I also suggest you try to keep that where clause in some "order" so it is easier to read.